# Activity has leaked window when going to next activity

Tags: android, memory, dialog

I am trying to display a `Progress Dialogue` when going from one `activity` to a second `activity`. Unfortunately I keep getting this error:

```
05-17 17:58:30.274  29115-29115/me.tb.player E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity me.tb.player.SkeletonActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1ec8d3e2 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
            at me.tb.player.SkeletonActivity$GetProgress.onPreExecute(SkeletonActivity.java:1140)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at me.tb.player.SkeletonActivity$13.onClick(SkeletonActivity.java:1178)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:160)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

What happens is that an `AlertDialog` pops up and if the user clicks yes, is taken to the next `activity`.

```
  private class GetProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog dialog1;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                dialog1 = new ProgressDialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(
                        SkeletonActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog));
            } else {
                dialog1 = new ProgressDialog(SkeletonActivity.this);
            }
            dialog1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog1.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateScore();
                    clearText();
                    turnComplete();
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute() {
            dialog1.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

And here is the `Dialogue`:

```
   public void messageAtEndOfTurn(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        GetProgress getProgress = new GetProgress();
                        getProgress.execute();
                    }
                }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                clear();
            }
        });

        mAlertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        mAlertDialog.show();
}
```

I believe the issue has to do with not properly calling `dismiss` on the `Alert Dialog` when going to the next activity. Or perhaps my `Progress Dialog` has an error. Can someone please help?

Alternatively, is there a simpler way to make a `Progress Dialog` when going from one `activity` to the next - Do I really need to use an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: It is because of improper dismiss

Comment: improper dismiss of the `progress dialog` - so how am I supposed to dismiss it?

Comment: ProgressDialog, not AlertDialog because I think once you hit any of the buttons of the AlertDialog, it automatically gets dismissed. Where is it that you invoke the next activity ?

Comment: What are you doing inside `turnComplete()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must dismiss the dialog before finishing the current activity.